# How to convert sql string datetime

Tags: sql-server, datetime

How do I convert/cast the string `April 04, 2016 12:00:00` to `DATETIME` in **sql server 2005**?

**UPDATE** I would like to compare dates like this :

```
SELECT * 
from ZeroAndLackingRequest  
WHERE request_date BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME,'April 04, 2016 12:00:00',103)  
                   AND CONVERT(DATETIME,'April 04, 2016 11:59:59',103)
```

but it is not working. Any Ideas why?

Comment: SELECT cast('April 04, 2016 12:00:00' AS datetime)

Comment: I have updated my question, kindly check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT cast('April 04, 2016 12:00:00' AS datetime)
```

OR

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,'April 04, 2016 12:00:00')
```

[For more details](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx)

Comment: Plz check the date you entered in where clause, the lowest date should be first (change to  eg:- SELECT * from ZeroAndLackingRequest 
WHERE request_date BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME,'April 01, 2016 12:00:00',103)  
 AND CONVERT(DATETIME,'April 05, 2016 11:59:59',103))

Comment: if you don't need to check the time, them you can COVERT to **DATE** instead of DATETIME

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from [ZeroAndLackingRequest] Z where Z.request_date =  CONVERT(datetime, 'April 04, 2016 12:00:00', 120)
```

remember I choose 120 style you can chooose 103 or any other please see below link.

For a full discussion of CAST and CONVERT, including the different date formatting options, see the MSDN Library Link below:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

If you want to compare

```
Select * from [ZeroAndLackingRequest] Z  
where cast(Z.request_date as datetime) >= cast('April 04, 2016 12:00:00' as datetime) 
and cast(Z.request_date as datetime) < cast('April 04, 2016 11:59:59' as datetime)
```